# SQL Server : Tables vs Cursors

Tags: sql-server

I'm asking for a high level understanding of what these two things are.

From what I've read, it seems that in general, a query with an `ORDER BY` clause returns a cursor, and basically cursors have order to them whereas tables are literally a set where order is not guaranteed.

What I don't really understand is, why are these two things talked about like two separate animals. To me, it seems like cursors are a subset of tables. The book I'm reading vaguely mentioned that

> "Some language elements and operations in SQL expect to work with
>   table results of queries and not with cursors; examples include table
>   expressions and set operators"

My question would be... why not? Why won't SQL handle it like a table anyways even if it's given an ordered set?

Just to clarify, I will type out the paragraph from the book:

> A query with an ORDER BY clause results in what standard SQL calls a cursor - a nonrelational result with order guaranteed among rows. You're probably wondering why it matters whether a query returns a table result or a cursor. Some language elements and operations in SQL expect to work with table results of queries and not with cursors; examples include table expressions and set operators..."

Comment: Book and exact quote please

Comment: @JamesZ, sure he does. SQL is built up on the set theory from one side and on the predicate logic on the other side.

Comment: Yeah - but I'm in the very early chapters where this concept is vaguely talked about. The book is T-Sql Fundamentals, Chapter 2, page 43. I think maybe I'm just misunderstanding what the author is trying to communicate.

Comment: **[Single-Table Queries in Microsoft SQL Server 2012](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2225058)** free chapter from book available for everyone.

Comment: The thing is that you shouldn't compare SQL Server cursors with what they call cursors. In the set theory a set is a set of unordered items. If you add ordering to it they say you get a cursor. They just call ordered set a cursor and this is not a cursor from SQL Server syntax. Why that made a difference in SQL Server in a CTE for example? Hmm I have no idea. We should ask someone from Microsoft.

Comment: "a query with an ORDER BY clause returns a cursor" - no, it returns a cup of coffee. WIthout being sarcastic, but where the heck did you pick up the rumor that a query with an orderby returns a cursor? You really think that depending on whether here is an orderby or not there will be a totally different mechanism (as in: cursor usage has a separate syntax in sql)?

Comment: Thanks Giorgi - I think this is making sense now as there are actually two different 'cursors' being talked about here.

Comment: Just for laugh. `A query with an ORDER BY clause results in what standard SQL calls a cursor—a nonrelational result with order guaranteed among rows.` from the book. Lol, what I am getting with `ORDER BY NEWID()` cursor or relational set?

Answer (score 1):

A table is a result set.  It has columns and rows.  You can join to it with other tables to either filter or combine the data in ONE operation:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.PK = T2.PK
```

A cursor is a variable that stores a result set.  It has columns, but the rows are inaccessible - except the top one!  You can't access the records directly, rather you must fetch them ONE ROW AT A TIME.

```
DECLARE TESTCURSOR CURSOR
   FOR SELECT * FROM Table1

OPEN TESTCURSOR 
FETCH NEXT FROM TESTCURSOR
```

You can also fetch them into variables, if needed, for more advanced processing.

Please let me know if that doesn't clarify it for you.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to this sentence,

> "Some language elements and operations in SQL expect to work with
>   table results of queries and not with cursors; examples include table
>   expressions and set operators"

I think the author is just saying that there are cases where it doesn't make sense to use an `ORDER BY` in a fragment of a query, because the `ORDER BY` should be on the outer query, where it will actually affect the final result of the query.

For instance, I can't think of any point in putting an `ORDER BY` on a `CTE` ("table expression") or on the Subquery in an `IN( )` expression.   **UNLESS** (in both cases) a `TOP n` was used as well.

When you create a `VIEW`, SQL Server will actually not allow you to use an `ORDER BY` unless a `TOP n` is also used.  Otherwise the `ORDER BY` should be specified when Selecting from the `VIEW`, not in the code of the `VIEW` itself.